# How do I listen for changes in array when the array is bound to a visbility propery in an UWP application

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a menu in a UWP application. I want to hide or show menu items depending on "roles" that I receive from an API.

Right now I am populating a `ObservableCollection<string>` where each string is a role.

On the `MenuItem`'s `Visibility` property I'm binding the `ObservableCollection` together with a `Converter` and `ConverterParameters`.

```
Visibility="{Binding Roles, Converter={StaticResource RolesToVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter='MyRoleToMatch', Mode=OneWay}"
```

This works very well if I populate the "roles" array in the constructor of the view so both the `Binding` and `Converter` is working as it should.

My problem is that I populate and clears the `ObservableCollection` from code behind but the `Binding` does not react on changes in the `Collection`.

Does anyone have any suggestion how to solve the problem?

Comment: Do you really `Clear()` the `Collection` or do you create a new one?

Comment: Calling `Clear` won't raise any event for the data-bound property which is required for the converter to be invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the data-bound `Roles` property for the framework to call the `Convert` method again.

This means that the class in which the `ObservableCollection<string>` property itself is defined must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. You can then raise the event for the `Roles` property like this, for example when the `CollectionChanged` is raised:

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Roles)));
```

Modifying the collection itself won't raise any event for the data-bound collection property.

Comment: But why? He should not be forced to do this as long as he binds to the `ObserveableCollection` which implements this by itsself and does not replace the collection instance.

Comment: Why what? There is no event raised to indicate that the `Roles` property has been updated when the collection is itself is modified.

Comment: When he "updates the collection", aka. calling `Add()`, `Remove()` and so on, there is no need to raise `PropertyChanged` for the `Roles` property, since it did in fact not change. The content changes of `ObserveableCollecion` should be handled already because `ObserveableCollecion` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` by itsself.

Comment: @Dominik: You are plain wrong. Again, the `ObservableCollection<T>` cannot raise an event for the object which where the data-bound `Roles` property is defined. You need to raise an event for this particular property for the converter to get called again. Setting the property to a new collection will work provided that the setter raises the `PropertyChanged` event.

Comment: okay for an in depth discussion I don't have the setup to prove right now unfortunately but I never implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on my ViewModel just to notify for data changes.
Also ms docs state: 
WPF provides the ObservableCollection<T> class, which is a built-in implementation of a data collection that implements the INotifyCollectionChanged interface.

Comment: Then you have never successfully used a converter that accepts a collection as its value either.

Comment: Alright, I just tried it. You are right. Then I'd suggest the OP to register `OnPropertyChanged` to `ObserveableCollection.CollectionChanged`

Comment: @Dominik: That's probably a good idea. I included this in my answer.

Comment: For now I have the observable collection in the code-behind for the page so I cannot derive the class from INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: The code-behind class should *implement* `INotifyPropertyChanged`. It's an interface. So yes, you certainly can.